# How to return data from a method that uses async functions?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm pretty new to using Express.js and I have an issue returning the data from the database query. The goal is to get user info from the table as JSON inside *userController* but only thing I get is *undefined*. I tried many different things but can't get my head around how to return the value from the method.

**db.js**

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');
var con = mysql.createPool({
    //db data here
});
module.exports = con;
```

**userController.js**

```
var User = require("../models/userModel");
exports.registerUser = function(req, res){
    if(req.method == 'POST'){
        var username = req.body.username;
        var email = req.body.email;
        //doing checks

        var u1 = new User(username, email);
        console.log(u1.getInfo());
    }
}
```

**userModel.js**

```
const db = require('../config/db');
module.exports = class User{
//constructor here

  getInfo(){
    try{
       var query = "SELECT * FROM users";
        db.query(query, function(err, data){
            return JSON.stringify(data);
        });
    }
    catch(err){
        return err;
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting undefined because the query need to wait the answer, and when you call getInfo(), the `return JSON.stringify(data);` are only execute when the query have the data.

You can use promise warper, because you need to wait to the database response. To use promises mysql2 have this package: `const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');`

Make your getInfo() function asynchronous

```
  async getInfo(){
    try{
       const res = await db.execute('SELECT * FROM users');
       return res;
    }
    catch(err){
        return err;
    }
  }
```

Then you can call the function with await:

```
exports.registerUser = async function(req, res){
    if(req.method == 'POST'){
        var username = req.body.username;
        var email = req.body.email;
        //doing checks

        var u1 = new User(username, email);
        console.log(await u1.getInfo());
    }
```

I cant test the code now, but it should work